# Android ClassNotFound

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am Developing an android application and when i start running my project it unfortunately stop due to error called classnotfound and i don't know how to fix that problem

here's my Logcat

```
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447): Process: com.example.elfaroukschool, PID:        17447
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at  android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:106)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at  android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at com.example.elfaroukschool.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
12-06 08:50:00.103: E/AndroidRuntime(17447):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 08:50:01.704: I/Process(17447): Sending signal. PID: 17447 SIG: 9
```

Here's My MainActivity Class

```
package com.example.elfaroukschool;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    // for color
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#28295b")));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView ig=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.igcse);
    TextView boys=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.boys);
    TextView girls=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.girls);

    ig.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ig.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    boys.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent b=new Intent(MainActivity.this,boys.class);
            startActivity(b);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    girls.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent s=new Intent(MainActivity.this,girls.class);
            startActivity(s);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I Also Made Another Classes And Mentioned Them In The Mainfest File

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Comment: This looks more like IntelliJ IDEA code than eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add the jar file to lib, android support is a library with source. try adding this lib by  [Adding Support Libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library)

If still not running OK. Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

clean your project and run

Also, you can go into Java Build Path > Order and Export tab.

Click everything in the list "Android Private Libraries".

Then "Project -> Clean".

Answer (score 0):

Problem occurs for me with projects which use Support library.

This thread helped me a lot to resolve ClassNotFoundException issue with ADT 22:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55304

The idea is to enable Android Private Libraries on Java Buils Path | Order and Export

1.Right click the project, and choose Properties

2.Go to Java Build Path-Order and Export.

3.Tick 'Android Private Libraries'

4.(Optional) Clean all projects if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Check your Manifeast did you include your class name `MainActivity`

```
<activity
            android:name="your_package_name.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```